# R - Bonferroni correction with p.adjust(), what's the correct n value?

Tags: r, bonferroni

I am trying to get the Bonferroni correction right.

Let's suppose I have a dataset with 100 p-values, 20 significant at minimum the 10% level (p-value < 0.1) and 80 not significant (p-value >= 0.1).

When applying the Bonferroni correction with R, using `p.adjust()` what's the correct `n` value?

**Shall I put `n = 100` (all p-values) or `n = 20` (only significant p-values)?**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter whether your p values are significant or not.  Your n is the number of tests (= p values) you want to correct for.  If you are interested in the results of all 100 tests, then n = 100.

Comment: so using n=100 should apply also if I am interested in correcting only the p-values that are significant?

Comment: Yes, you should not correct based on p values.  You should control your Type 1 error rate for multiple tests, before you run the tests.  First determine how many tests you actually want to run.  You get penalized for running unnecessary tests.

Comment: thanks. But with my real data out of 1,000 tests I only get 2 significant p-values after the Bonferroni correction. That’s too strict I think.

Comment: There are other corrections that could give you more power to detect significant effects.  Important points are: 1) why are you running 100 (1,000?) tests?  2) why do you sound like your goal is to find significance?  This shouldn't be the case, you should aim to make correct inferences and correction--Bonferroni or other--helps you control your Type 1 error rate, which helps in that direction.

Comment: I am correlating 1,000 time series of a physical variable with 1 time series of another physical variable

Comment: I don't know your field, design, or research questions, so it is beyond me whether you really need all such tests.  If this is exploratory research, perhaps consider other alternatives than NHST and p values.